# RIGOL DS1054Z Fixed trigger time for sweeping using a FeelTech digital signal generator

Tags: function-generator, trigger

**How do you properly setup a frequency sweep with a digital signal generator and a RIGOL oscilloscope?**

I've got a setup similar to one in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ni07A7sZCPM, showing it's possible. Still, I can't find anywhere a clear instruction on how to set a fixed trigger time just like the author of the video did.

So, I've got very popular Rigol DS1054Z (in the video, the author uses a RIGOL DS1102E) and a FeelTech FY3200S function generator, which is a cheap generator from china, with good reviews in general.

Since it's a digital generator, it's providing only a TTL square wave, and no ramp is available. It would seem, the author of the video only has a single wire connected to the oscilloscope anyway. Please advise.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Questions here are required to stand on their own, external links (especially to videos) may only supplement, the question is required to make sense without following/watching them.

Comment: I'm trying to do a swipe of frequencies, so that the function generator sweeps from 0Hz to 20kHz in 1 second, and the oscilloscope gets triggered at near 1Hz and fills up the screen by the time 20kHz are reached. So far I got a semi-satisfactory result with Trigger mode: Time out, set to 1ms at the TTL input. Alas it seems like a workaround and much simpler solution should be there.

Comment: Can you just set it for single capture with a 1 second horizontal width?  And either hope it starts on the initial output, or hit both buttons together?   If you capture a bit too much you can scroll the screen afterwards to show the part you care about.  A better setup would use a trigger output from the generator to the external trigger or another channel on the scope.

Comment: There's no signal output in that cheap generator, at least that I'm aware of. But! There's TTL! 
I've managed to get a stable result by using a timeout trigger of around 1ms, so that when TTL's square wave (half cycle) is longer than 1ms, the scope triggers. The trigger event happens somewhere between 0Hz and 5Hz, which works good enough, so that the waveform doesn't wiggle left and right. 
Horizontal slider helps to nudge the waveform to the left border of the screen.

That's a workaround, and I hope not the only one :)